# Считать заголовок сообщения RabbitMQ (C#)

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Пишу обработчик сообщений на C#. В мою очередь RabbitMQ приходят сообщения с определенными заголовками. Мне необходимо считать один из них (X-App-Uid, выделен на рисунке). Каким способом это можно сделать?
[image: Искомый заголовок]

Comment: а какую библиотеку для работы с RabbitMq вы используете?

Comment: Я использую nuget-пакет RabbitMQ.Client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если взять простейший пример из документации `RabbitMq.Client`: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html, там есть часть кода для обработки сообщений:

```cs
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    var value = ea.BasicProperties.Headers["X-App-Uid"];
    // ...
};
```

Для получения доступа к заголовкам, вы можете использовать `BasicProperties.Headers`.